# Mongodb takes 3 minutes to connect

Tags: macos, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just reinstalled Mongodb on my mac (fresh install of mountain lion 10.8) and now my apps are taking ~3 mins to connect.

I put together a simple node script to test this:

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/passport-mongox',function(err){
  var stop = (new Date()).getTime();

  console.log('Took this long: ',(stop-start) / 1000 );
 });
```

Both times were 175.273 and 175.316 seconds.

When I connect to an external, hosted mongodb it connects in less than a second,

Any idea why this would happen? Here is my mongo.log:

```
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2262 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=w
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Fri Feb  1 12:43:25 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Feb  1 12:43:26 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Feb  1 12:43:26 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Feb  1 12:44:05 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52137 #1 (1 connection now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:44:40 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52152 #2 (2 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:45:15 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52201 #3 (3 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:45:50 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52298 #4 (4 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:46:25 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52325 #5 (5 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:51:26 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:52325 (4 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:51:26 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:52201 (4 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:51:26 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:52298 (4 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:51:26 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:52137 (4 connections now open)
Fri Feb  1 12:51:26 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:52152 (4 connections now open)
```

Comment: perhaps move the start to after the 'require' statement? (just so we are 100% sure that the connect is what is taking so long).  As an aside, what is your machine's memory usage like?

Comment: Moving it speeds it up by half a second, so no real difference. I have 1.5gigs of free memory ATM, so its not that.

Comment: try reducing the connection pool size down to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: Tried bringing it down to 1 and it now takes 35 seconds - some improvement but still too slow

Comment: Ok. So. - It likely isn't getting bottlenecked on some disk thing (ie. lots of memory + no data in a new db + no other users). - It isn't hitting some weird library loading snag. - It isn't taking an equal amount of time on all the connections, most of the penalty is on the first connection attempt.

Comment: Could always try the good old computer restart?

Comment: Does it take that long when you connect with the command line utility too (i.e. running mongo) ?

Answer (score 10):

Answer from [mongoose.js](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#slow-localhost)

**Cause**: 
The underlying MongoDB driver defaults to looking for IPv6 addresses,
so the most likely cause is that your localhost DNS mapping isn't configured to handle IPv6.

**Solution** : 
Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost or use the family option as shown in the [connection docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options).

`mongoose.connect(url, {family:4}, function(err, connection) {
    connection.db(your_db_name);
});`

Comment: this solved my problem, tnx.

Answer (score 6):

So the answer came from [@AdamMeghji](http://twitter.com/AdamMeghji) on twitter.

My hosts file has always looked like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.com
127.0.0.1 wes.dev
```

I switched that to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost test.com wes.dev
```

and connections went back to 0.015 seconds.

Comment: It really solved very long connection! OS X El Capitan. I've tried mongodb drivers 1.4, 2.0 and 2.1, node 4.1 and 5.4 and mongodb 3.0.6. Only editing /etc/hosts solved this issue. Very strange behaviour.

Comment: @wesbos could you clarify a bit about the format used? I'm not really sure what it's supposed to mean

Answer (score 0):

use this "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/database_name"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.